# angular-cli ng command gives "Unexpected token ="

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-cli

I installed Angular CLI using **npm** using this commande line :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

The installation was done with succes but when I try to use the **ng** commande then I had this error :

```
root@errabi-Lenovo-G560:/home/errabi/Desktop# ng help
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:17
    constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = []) {
                                                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Any idea about this problem Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of node do you have installed?

Comment: I use this version v4.2.6

Comment: For running angular-cli, your node version should be atleast 6

Comment: Yes it was a version problem thx guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you have node v 4.2.6
Below are the requisites for the angular/cli as per documentation.

> Prerequisites
>
> Both the CLI and generated project have dependencies that require Node
>   6.9.0 or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher.